With Gravity Forms, how do I group multiple forms together and set an entry limit for the group?
I am working with Gravity Forms to create an appointment booking system using gappointments addon. The challenge I am facing is that I need to limit the total entries per day of multiple forms together.
Gravity Forms allow limiting the entries of a single form, however after researching I could not find a way to group multiple forms and set the total number of entries allowed per day of the forms group.
So is there a way I can achieve this functionality via custom code or plugin?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

this is possible with Limit Submissions and this snippet that allows you to apply a limit feed to multiple forms:
https://gravitywiz.com/snippet-library/gpls-apply-same-feed-to-group/

Thanks for your answer, Dave. I needed guidance, I think I can figure it out now after going through your plugin and snippet.

one question please. This allows all the forms to have the same limit on submissions, for example, I can define the submission limit as 1 and then submit once on each form with the form ID defined in the code snippet.
But what if I want a collective submission limit of all the forms with the form IDs defined in the code snippet? For example, the total limit of submissions allowed for Form1, Form2 and Form3 is 2, then how can I go about it?
I appreciate your help.

Ah, you can make it collective by returning false with this filter:
https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gpls_apply_limit_per_form/

Thanks for your answer, Dave. The collective limit is not working correctly for the form IDs defined in the code. The limit is still working per form. Perhaps I am putting the code wrong, could you please guide me further on this? Where should I put the returning false filter? Thank you.
